# gulp sass is not compiling my .min file, yet no errors are thrown

Tags: css, node.js, sass, gulp

New to gulp, everything is installed and it runs properly

gulp --version
CLI version: 2.3.0
Local version: 4.0.2

when I change my scss file, nothing at all happens.. gulp is happily running in terminal

```
[13:34:16] Starting 'compile_scss'...
[13:34:16] Starting 'compile_scss'...
[13:34:16] Finished 'compile_scss' after 12 ms
[13:34:16] Starting 'detect_change_scss'...
[13:34:16] Finished 'detect_change_scss' after 16 ms
[13:34:16] Finished 'compile_scss' after 32 ms*
```

this is my code

```
'use strict';

 
 var gulp = require('gulp');
 var sass = require('gulp-sass');
 var minifyCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
 var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
 var renamed = require('gulp-rename');
 var changed = require('gulp-changed');

   

 var SCSS_SRC = './src/Assets/scss/**/*.scss';
 var SCSS_DEST = './src/Assets/css';

 function compile_scss (done) {
    gulp.src(SCSS_SRC)
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(minifyCSS())
    .pipe(renamed({ suffix: '.min' }))
    .pipe(changed(SCSS_DEST))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(SCSS_DEST));
    done();
   }


  function detect_change_scss (done) {
    gulp.watch(SCSS_SRC)
    done();
  }


 gulp.task("compile_scss", gulp.series(compile_scss, detect_change_scss, ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell gulp what function to run when it detects a change.  So try this instead:

```
function detect_change_scss (done) {
  gulp.watch(SCSS_SRC, gulp.series(compile_scss))
  done();
}
```